# Check if two given strings are isomorphic to each other c++, not sure why it's wrong

Tags: c++, isomorphic

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t) {
        vector <int> sfreq (26,0);
        vector <int> tfreq (26,0);
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {
            sfreq[s[i]-'a']++;
            tfreq[t[i]-'a']++; 
        }
        
        if (sfreq != tfreq) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
        
        };
```

Hi, this is my code in c++, I saw something similar from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-strings-are-isomorphic-to-each-other/ but my answer shows it's wrong. Can anyone please tell me why it's wrong?

Comment: what is `- 'a'`? I don't get it

Comment: to make characters to integer type

Comment: Right, I get it now my C++ is rusty

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you are just counting the frequency, not considering the pattern

Comment: As I read it AAABBCA is Isomorphic by the linked definition to XXXYYZX because the mapping A->X, B->Y and C->Z maps the first string to the second. It looks like you're looking for anagrams. Also your code is pretty fragile because it's undefined if the strings are not lowercase alpha.

Answer (score 2):

You completely misunderstood the description.

Your question suggests that any permutation of characters in input do not change answer. Also you assumed that histograms are equal.

Position of character is important. Each position in both strings creates a unique pair.

Here my code which passed:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    static bool canMapInOneDirection(std::string_view s, std::string_view t)
    {
        const auto n = s.size();
        std::array<char, 128> mapping{};
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (mapping[s[i]] == 0) mapping[s[i]] = t[i];
            else if (mapping[s[i]] != t[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;   
        
    }
    bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t)
    {
        return s.size() == t.size() && canMapInOneDirection(s, t) && canMapInOneDirection(t, s);
    }
};
```

And test cases you can use to test your code:

| s | t | answear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "a" | "b" | true |
| "aa" | "bb" | true |
| "ab" | "aa" | false |
| "aabbcc" | "aabcbc" | false |

https://godbolt.org/z/61EcTK5fq

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing a loop.

> Note that, it still requires more corner case checking to make it fully work. The second approach properly handles all cases.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t) {
        vector <int> sfreq (26,0);
        vector <int> tfreq (26,0);

        for (int i=0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            sfreq[s[i]-'a']++;
            tfreq[t[i]-'a']++; 
        }
        
        // character at the same index (can be different character) should have the same count.
        for(int i= 0; i < s.size(); i++)
            if (sfreq[s[i]-'a'] != tfreq[t[i]-'a']) return false;

        return true;
    }
};
```

But the above solution only works if there is direct index mappping between characters. Like, `AAABBCA` and `XXXYYZX`. But fails for `bbbaaaba` and `aaabbbba`. Also, no uppercase, lowercase handled. The link you shared contains the wrong implementation which is mentioned in the comment.

The solution below works as I tested.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t) {
        vector<int> scount(128, -1), tcount(128, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
            auto schar = s[i], tchar = t[i];
            if (scount[schar] == -1) {
                scount[schar] = tchar;
                if (tcount[tchar] != -1) return false;
                else tcount[tchar] = schar;
            } else if (scount[schar] != tchar) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Try this input: `aabbcc` `xxyzyz` I think proper answer is `false`

Comment: The second solution will give `false` as the output. `if (tcount[tchar] != -1) return false;` this line in particular will handle this case.

Comment: Also as stated in the answer, the first snippet has lots of corner cases missing. The `geeksforgeeks` link also has a faulty implementation, which does not handle all cases that you have stated. That's why the second snippet is given instead of modifying the first one to make it work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This not a question about anagrams or directly about character frequencies. It is about pattern. It's about having a character-by-character mapping that makes one string into the other. AABC is isomorphic to XXYZ but not isomorphic to BCAA.

When we talk about Isomorphism (same form) it's often a good idea to look for a signature representation.
So instead of determining if two strings are isomorphic I've decided to define a unique signature representation and determine isomorphism if two strings map to the same signature.

I've used `std::vector<char>` for the signature representation such that the first character (if any) is assigned 0 the second (previously unseen) character 1 and so on.

So a string like `MOON` has signature `{0,1,1,2}` because the middle characters are the only repeats. `MOON` is isomorphic to `BOOK` but not `NOON`.

The advantage of such a strategy is that if many strings are to be compared to find groups of mutually isomorphic strings each string need only be converted to its signature once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>


std::vector<char> get_signature(const std::string& str){
    std::vector<char> result;
    std::unordered_map<char,char> map;
    char curr{1};
     
  for(auto cchar : str){
    char& c{map[cchar]};
    if(c==0){
        c=curr++;
     }
     result.emplace_back(c-1);
   }
    return result;
}


int check_signature(const std::string& str, const std::vector<char>& expect ){
    const auto result{get_signature(str)};
    return result==expect?0:1;
}


int main() {
     int errors{0};
     {
        const std::string str{"ABCDE"};
        const std::vector<char> signat{0,1,2,3,4};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     {
        const std::string str{"BABY"};
        const std::vector<char> signat{0,1,0,2};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     {
        const std::string str{"XXYZX"};
        const std::vector<char> signat{0,0,1,2,0};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     {
        const std::string str{"AABCA"};
        const std::vector<char> signat{0,0,1,2,0};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     {
        const std::string str{""};
        const std::vector<char> signat{};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     {
        const std::string str{"Z"};
        const std::vector<char> signat{0};
        errors+=check_signature(str,signat);
     }
     if(get_signature("XXYZX")!=get_signature("AABCA")){
        ++errors;
     }
     
      if(get_signature("MOON")==get_signature("AABCA")){
        ++errors;
     }
     if(get_signature("MOON")!=get_signature("BOOK")){
        ++errors;
     }
     if(get_signature("MOON")==get_signature("NOON")){
        ++errors;
     }

     if(errors!=0){
        std::cout << "ERRORS\n";
     }else{
        std::cout << "SUCCESS\n";
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output: `SUCCESS`